# Why does float('nan') == float('nan') return False?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nan

I am curious to know why

```
float('nan') == float('nan')
```

returns False.

I noticed this while debugging and realizing that if I had `foo = float('nan')` then to my surprise `foo in [bar, float('nan')]` always returned False.

Comment: Because that's one of the fundamental properties of nan: all comparison operations always return false.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  Really? Shame on me for not knowing that.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/5014455) an answer to the *why is that in the standard* question from someone who apparently was actually on the committee...

Comment: The _real_ answer is that the committee was full of electrical engineers who don't understand how programming works. Most languages in 1985 had comparison operators that define a total ordering—possibly as a partial function that's a total ordering where it's defined (in Python terms, that means they either order things sensibly or raise an exception)—but definitely not a total function that's a partial ordering. So "signaling NaN" makes some sense, but "quiet NaN' comparisons do not. Unfortunately, in 2018, the general rule is even more widespread than in 1985, but a violation for NaN is too.