# python float('nan') vs math.nan

Tags: python, nan

I read [Why does float('nan') == float('nan') return False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643187/why-does-floatnan-floatnan-return-false)
and accept that `float('nan) != float('nan')`. I modified my code to successfully use `math.isnan()`.

But if `float('nan')` cannot be found in lists, why can `math.nan` be found in lists?

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.nan in [ 1.0, 2.0, float('nan'), 5.0 ]
False
>>> float('nan') in [ 1.0, 2.0, float('nan'), 5.0 ]
False
>>> math.nan in [ 1.0, 2.0, math.nan, 5.0 ]
True
```

Comment: Because it's checked for by _identity_ - `math.nan is math.nan`. `float('nan')`, by contrast, creates a new object each time it's called.

Comment: Not obvious but makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can get the same result by defining `nan = float('nan')` and using that (which is what is essentially happening when you use `math.nan`)